# Wine is very yeasty

Tags: yeast

this is my first wine experience. 
I used store bought grape juice, due to lockdown, i added bread yeast.

The bubbling stopped about 2 week. So i racked and tried to drink. 
Since it is red wine, i dont know if there is fogging due to yeast. i have no experience

I found high yeasty taste and stomach pain.

My question
1. did i drink very early
2. Should i rack 2 or 3 more time
3. Should i try a finning agent.

Stuck at Home and this wine... dont know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

When using bread yeast, wine will have more yeasty taste than when prepared with wine yeast.
How much yeast did you put in? 
2 weeks isn't too early if you're bothered about it's taste only. Did it give you any kick?
You can buy a hydrometer to check alcohol production.
Fining agent might help a bit, you can use bentonite powder.

Answer (score 1):

My answer to your 3 questions is YES.

1- It is a bit early to drink.  Give it at least 2 more weeks.
2- Give it some time to sediment and rack.  Usually first racking is at the end of fermentation.
3- A fining agent will help to get rid of the remaining yeast in suspension.

I can also suggest filtering if fining is not an option.  All this will help.

Comment: I would say wait months. Wine is rarely served fresh, months and years rather than days and weeks. That would also allow the taste to mellow out and the yeast to clean up. Bread yeast is not necessarily very alcohol-tolerant so the results may be so-so.

Comment: It all depends on the quality of grapes, some wines are better to drink young.  Many wine kits are bottled after 4 weeks and I do not think that grape juice will age well, but I would wait a minimum of 4 weeks before bottling, then wait again 2 more weeks before I try one.